# Azure Communication Service - pre create a video meeting for specified date and time and record the link

Tags: azure, azure-communication-services

Azure Communication Service -
Is there a way we can pre create a video meeting for specified date and time and record the link so that it can be sent to the participants. and invoked at specified time

Comment: To clarify are you trying to do ACS to ACS call or Teams to ACS? if it is the latter you can use [Teams interoperability][1].

Comment: ACS to ACS call , pre booking is what we are looking

Comment: Also seeking an answer to this question. @Varan did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, although it's not the best solution. It IS a solution.

MS has offered a JS option that wraps the react components.
https://github.com/Azure/communication-ui-library/tree/main/samples/StaticHtmlComposites

Directly from the sample,

```
 const callAdapter = await callComposite.loadCallComposite({
  containerId: 'video-call',
  groupId: '', // Provide any GUID to join a group
  displayName: displayName,
  userId: user,
  token: token
});
```

in my testing I was able to plug in any randomly generated GUID, and share a link with that guid to my co-workers who were able to join the video call.

Hope that helps lead to a better solution. I'm still trying to get this thing working friendly with MVC. I may update when I get that working.